# Undetermined coefficients guessing particular solution's shape

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I try to find general solution for:
$$y'' - y = 8 t e^t$$
I find comp. as $(D-1)(D+1)=0$ and general solution of it as $y_g= C_1 e^t + C_2 e^-t$
at this point.

I know particular solution shape is:
$$y= A t e^t+ B t^2 e^t$$
But what is the way to find it? In other words how can I guess that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the [*Method of Undetermined Coefficients*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx).

The homogeneous solution is:

$$y_h(t) = c_1 e^t + c_2 e^{-t}$$

Since we have an $e^t$ in the homogeneous, the method has us multiply by an extra $t$ term, so we try:

$$y_p(t) = t(a e^t + b t e^t)$$

You can see a good discussion of the reasons and more examples on the linked web site, particularly example $10$. It shows that you try several approaches until you find one that works. After a little experience, you see a better approach for a choice as there is a pattern.

Comment: Thanks alot link is very helpful

Comment: Needs a TU! + 1